# Is PHP Cache shared between users?

Tags: php, caching

Take a look at this code:

```
$cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Output',
                             'File',
                             $frontendOptions,
                             $backendOptions);

// we pass a unique identifier to the start() method
if(!$cache->start('mypage')) {
    // output as usual:

    echo 'Hello world! ';
    echo 'This is cached ('.time().') ';

    $cache->end(); // the output is saved and sent to the browser
}
```

As this [doc](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.introduction.html) explains, the above will not get into block statement if it has already been processed, consequently, the time won't refresh. Lets say the expire time is configured to 30 seconds.

Visitor A comes and the Output is cached, so obviously, the visitor would see the same time for multiple refresh for 30 seconds. My question is that if Visitor B comes along the same time, will he see the same time as Visitor A because its already cached or the caching will be user specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, he will, because that the reason, why one should use caches: Don't process stuff for every single user over and over again. You *could* create the cache-ID with something user specific

```
$cache->start('mypage'.$userId);
```

but then you should ask yourself if it's really worth to get cached.

Comment: Just cleared my query. It may be good enough when you are dealing with users obsessed with refreshing page every single second.

Comment: The moment it hits the application it's too late to keep them away anyway. You should consider using a more powerful caching strategy like a reverse-proxy and/or browser-caching.  Also think about, wether a user really needs the current time on the page and I guess caching is more expensinve here, then just echo the current time again. Use application-based caching for _expensive_ tasks only, or it will _slow down_ your application.

Comment: The time was just an example. I was learning Zend_Cache. Is this caching method expensive and inefficient in general?

Comment: @Shubham It depends ;) For example reading a file and then caching it's contents is usually just useless, especially when using the File-Backend, because you replace "reading from a file" with "lookup the cache file and reading the cache file, or reading the original file and writing to the cache file".

Comment: Right now, I fancy to use it to fetch latest 10 posts sorted by date from MySQL database and paginate the URLs. I think caching can be good.?

Comment: Think so, but in how is this user specific?